# Bad layout in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Sometimes there's an extra space after short comments.

[image: bug]

As above...

Comment: the spacing looks pretty much the same as our other sites, and [previously Sketchy](http://i.imgur.com/fufk3.png), because the gap needs to be there for the flag icon.

Comment: @Jin the spacing is there, the hideous lines that make look bigger, are not. In any case, the point is that the gap is much more noticeable than the other sites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that spacing is there because of the FLAG button.

Comment: I get that there's the flag on hover -- the gap looks unbalanced though, possibly because of the horizontal lines? On other sites, the gap looks well balanced.